# C++: interfacing TA-lib with a circular FIFO queue

Tags: c++, ta-lib

I'd like to understand if there's a way to pass to the C++ [TA-lib](http://ta-lib.org/d_api/d_api.html) library a custom structure (a circular, FIFO, queue ) instead of a simple array.
The Circular queue is my main memory element for storing a fixed number of ticks ( to have `O(1)` efficiency for the `add(tick)` ).

What I'm looking for is a library that accepts an iterator-like interface to calculate indicators but I can't imagine a way to make the TA-lib accept such an object.

Answer (score 0):

You shall take a look on this fork of TA Lib: https://github.com/trufanov-nok/ta-lib-rt
Instead of arrays of data it's designed to use one input value per time while storing indicator progress in state object. In a nutshell instead of
`TA_IndicatorX(params, input_data[], output_data[]);`
you can use:

```
state = TA_IndicatorX_State(params);
foreach (input_val in input_data[])
    TA_IndicatorX(state, input_val, output_val);

TA_IndicatorX_State_Free(state);
```

Comment: Really an interesting fork, I will give it a look, Thanks!